# kotlin Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceButton' in current theme

Tags: android, xml

this is my activity_register.xml file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >   
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutRegisUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRegisUsername">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Usename" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutRegisPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRegisPassword">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Password" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutRegisRepeatPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRegisUsername">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisRepeatPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Repeat Password" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTanggalLahir">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email Address" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutTanggalLahir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="522dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etTanggalLahir"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Tanggal Lahir" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutTelepon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="522dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etTelepon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Telepon" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/brightBlue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAlreadyHaveAnAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Already have an account?"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textBtnSignUp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBtnSignIn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@color/brightBlue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_loading"
        layout="@layout/layout_loading"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it said Render Problem Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceButton' in current theme. i dont know where i should use textAppearanceButton. i already tried place

```
android:textAppearance="@color/teal_200"
```

in text button and it give more rendering problem

> Style ResourceReference{namespace=apk/res-auto, type=color, name=teal_200} is not of type STYLE (instead color)
> Failed to find style with 2131034719

. can someone help me?

Comment: I run into same problem, did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:N:N:N` in your build.gradle.
Look here please: [Render Problems with TabLayout and ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573385/render-problems-with-tablayout-and-viewholder)

This works for me.