# Render Problems with TabLayout and ViewHolder

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-design-library

I am currently unable to render am activity with just a TabLayout and ViewPager. I am getting this error:

`Style ResourceReference{namespace=apk/res-auto, type=attr, name=textAppearanceButton} is not of type STYLE (instead attr)`

From the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CompoundInterest">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabAbout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabCalculator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculator" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I added the TabLayout and ViewPager to an otherwise blank, new layout and they have never rendered, even after being 'connected' to the fragments.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the `Android` View, find the `Gradle Scripts` - `build.gralde(Module :App)` then edit it.
change

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'`

to

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'`

Finally, click `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, wait a minute, it would be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a problem with version 1.8.0.

Other Material Design examples
TabItems in TabLaout are also having rendering issues.

Downgrading to 1.7.0 works fine.

Comment: Problem is still present in 1.9.0 downgrading did the job. Thanks!!