# Android Studio Preview Stops Working When Adding Tab Item to Tab Layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-tablayout

I've noticed the preview crashing on many PCs not just mine, but the last problem I'm experiencing is when I add a TabItem inside a TabLayout, and I can't find any solution. I've tried the following:

- Clean Project, Rebuild Project
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Restarting my laptop
- Checking for any errors in that layout (there is none, just warnings about extracting strings)
- Checking the material components version (I have the current latest which is 1.8.0)

It might be something dumb that I forgot but right now I can't think of anything. Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.AdminActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/adminTab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/befc_blue"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/befc_blue">


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/chart"
            android:text="Reports" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/croissant"
            android:text="Hot Potatoes" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

These are the errors I get:
[image: Errors]

[image: First Error]

[image: Second Error]

[image: Third Error]

I've tried to add the default material design style to the tab layout but it didn't work

Comment: Provide error logs.

Comment: @deadfish what error logs?

Comment: Something is crashing - so there should be a log what caused it.

Comment: @deadfish I edited my post, you can see what errors I get

Comment: `textAppearanceTitleSmall` - where do you use it?

Comment: Are you using new design? https://material.io/blog/migrating-material-3

Comment: @deadfish yes, i found a solution, just do it programmatically, i put an empty TabLayout in my XML and added the TabItems in my kotlin code

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this too, it seems like it's a known issue with the recommendation to downgrade to 1.17.0. [Render Problems with TabLayout and ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573385/render-problems-with-tablayout-and-viewholder)

I did find a workaround, it's not the best solution but I was able to work around the preview breaking by removing the tabs from XML, then adding them in programatically.

```
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"))
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"))
```

It made it so I could still see the rest of my preview, which unblocked me.  I also think Android Studio focuses on Compose layout fixes vs XML. So not sure if this will get fixed.